# JPA detached object and primary key

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Thanks in advance for all your help.

I have an detached object with child objects. I have to insert or delete the child objects in order. So I am changing the primary key values of the child. Then I remove every child from the database. Then recreate all the child objects but eclipselink is complaining about the primary key already exist can not update database
Here is my code

```
Quotation q = ejbFacade.find(selected.getQuotationPK());
    for (QTitle qt : q.getQTitleList()) {
        for (QActivity qa : qt.getQActivityList()) {
            for (QCategorywork qc : qa.getQCategoryworkList()) {
                for (QManual qm : qc.getQManualList()) {
                    qmFacade.remove(qm);
                }
                for (QProduct qp : qc.getQProductList()) {
                    qpFacade.remove(qp);
                }
                qcFacade.remove(qc);
            }
            qaFacade.remove(qa);
        }
        qtFacade.remove(qt);
    }
    for (QTitle qt : selected.getQTitleList()) {
        qtFacade.create(qt);
        for (QActivity qa : qt.getQActivityList()) {
            qaFacade.create(qa);
            for (QCategorywork qc : qa.getQCategoryworkList()) {
                qcFacade.create(qc);
                for (QManual qm : qc.getQManualList()) {
                    qmFacade.create(qm);
                }
                for (QProduct qp : qc.getQProductList()) {
                    qpFacade.create(qp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ejbFacade.merge(selected);
    ejbFacade.refresh(selected);
```

The object selected is detached and all the children has cascadetype.all set.
May be there is some other efficient way of doing the above. Any advice!!

Comment: Please show what you mean when you say you change the primary key value of the child.  what is the exact  exception and stack?  As the answer below suggested, JPA does not allow changing primary keys, so these operations should be completely isolated in their own transactions - just because you think it is inserting a new entity doesn't mean it is maintaining references or caching it as it needs to.  You might try adding your modified getQTitleList list to the Quotation that was read in, as change tracking might not be accounting for changes to foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

you say:

> I remove every child from the database.

and you also say:

> Then recreate all the child objects

Please try to execute those two operations in their own transaction boundary. You will surely see the

> complaining about the primary key already exist

has gone.

Comment: The childs are recreated correctly in the database. The problem comes when I try to edit the parent object